# Swagger annotation when using an object as QueryParam not working as expected

Tags: java, annotations, jersey, swagger, jax-rs

Hello I am using Jackson/Jersey, Swagger annotations and a JAX-RS ParamConverter, to be able to deserialize Dates in my query params:

```
@QueryParam("_targetDate._ge")
@Parameter(in = ParameterIn.QUERY, name = "_targetDate._ge",
        required = false, allowEmptyValue = false, schema = @Schema(implementation = String.class, type = "string", format = "date"))
private Date initialTargetDate;
```

[Swagger rendering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/guccX.png)

But even though I am stating for Swagger that this field should be a String, via (Schema/implementation annotation), it is being rendered as an Object instead of a String. Any idea what can I be missing?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the type of initialTargetDate to String

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That's the point, I want it to be a Date, I have a ParamConverter that deals with the serialization. Of course the query param is a String, and I want Swagger to state that. I have been debugging the code in Swagger annotations, seems that either be have a bug there, or the Swagger annotations guys really want you to avoid overriding the schema type.